# Type User[] has no properties in common with type 'User' ngrx angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-reducers

I am trying to get user data using `ngrx`. Below is related code:

**user.actions.ts:**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'src/app/api/models/user';

export enum UserActionTypes {
    LOAD_USER = "[User] Load Pfas",
    LOAD_USER_SUCCESS = "[User] Load Pfas Success",
    LOAD_USER_FAIL = "[User] Load Pfas Fail",
}

export class LoadUser implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER
}

export class LoadUserSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS
    constructor(public payload: User[]) {}
}

export class LoadUserFail implements Action {
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_FAIL
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type Action = LoadUser | LoadUserSuccess | LoadUserFail;
```

**user.effects.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import * as UserActions from './user.actions';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/api/services/user.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/api/models/user';
import { Pfa } from '../../shared/pfa.module';

@Injectable()
export class UserEffect {
    constructor( private action$: Actions, private userService: UserService ) {}

    @Effect()
    loadUser$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe ( ofType<UserActions.LoadUser>(UserActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER), mergeMap((actions: UserActions.LoadUser) => this.userService.ApiUsersValidateGet().pipe( map( (u: User[]) => new UserActions.LoadUserSuccess(u) ) --<here getting an error,
    catchError(err => of(new UserActions.LoadUserFail(err))) ) ) )
}
```

**user.reducers.ts:**

```
import * as userActions from '../user/user.actions';
import * as fromRoot from '../../../app-states/app.state';
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { User } from 'src/app/api/models/user';

export interface UserState {
    user: User[],
    loading: boolean,
    loaded: boolean,
    error: string
}

export interface AppState extends fromRoot.AppState {
    user: UserState
}

export const initialState: UserState = {
    user: [],
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    error: ""
}

export function userReducer ( state = initialState, action: userActions.Action ):
UserState {
    switch(action.type) {
        case userActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case userActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                loaded: true,
                user: action.payload
            }
        }
        case userActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_USER_FAIL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                user: [],
                loading: false,
                loaded: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}

const getUserFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<UserState>("user");

export const getUser = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.user
);

export const getUserLoading = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.loading
);

export const getUserLoaded = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.loaded
);

export const getError = createSelector(
    getUserFeatureState,
    (state: UserState) => state.error
);
```

I am getting below error in `user.effects.ts` file:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.   Type 'User[]' has no properties in common with
>   type 'User'

Comment: please properly format your effects code.

Comment: are you sure this.userService.ApiUsersValidateGet() returns an Observable<User[]> and not Observable<User>

Answer (score 1):

I  think the error is here:

`map( (u: User[]) => new UserActions.LoadUserSuccess(u)`

If you use `map()`, you iterate through the data set. That means that within your `map()` function you have only one user as argument.

Try this:

`tap( (u: User[]) => new UserActions.LoadUserSuccess(u)`

Comment: i did this `map( (u: User) => new UserActions.LoadUserSuccess(u)` but still an error

Comment: `Currently it takes a user array, so you might want to fix that as well.` - How?

Comment: I don't know what else the class is used for. If for nothing else, just change the parameter of your constructor of LOAD_USER_SUCCESS to ```constructor(public payload: User) {}```

Comment: it is used in reducer, giving error there! If I do `constructor(public payload: User) {}`

Comment: this error : `Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]'.
  Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more`

Comment: Yea, I see. So then the constructor has to take an array of ```User```, I was wrong with that. But the map won't help you here because you're iterating through a data set and call ```new UserActions.LoadUserSuccess(u)``` for each user. You could try to replace ```map()``` with ```tap()``` because that takes the whole array and does something with it. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: error: `Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<User[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<User, User[]>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<User>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
      Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more`

Comment: Would be more polite without the exlamation marks...
Then I cannot help you, sorry, I guess you have to debug...